# Rows decrements in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have data in three col: account_id, date paid and amount. What I need is to decrement values in the col C by one per account. If another payment was made, add the new payment plus the last decrement value. After trying with analytical queries and simple calculator, I feel that there is no other way but to do it with js. Have you had a similar use case?

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Updated:
[image]

Comment: you can try `Group by` step using the `Cumulative sum` (include all rows) to calculate the running sum.

Comment: @jxc, thank you for the suggestion but it won't work as I need to decrement the values by one and as soon as the new payment is made, add the new amount the latest decrement value.

Comment: just add one field with `Calculator` step using `NVL(A,B)` where A is `amount` and B is a constant field `-1` which you can also define in Calculator step. then aggregate (running sum) on this new field.

Comment: Hm, like to group by as the first step? And then, calculator? I don't see running sum in Group by.

Comment: `Calculator --> Group by`, in `Group By` step, Type=`Cumulative sum(all rows option only!)`, make sure you selected the option `Include all rows`.

Comment: @jxc, I feel something is missing as the subtraction doesn't happen - see the updated question.

Comment: My apologies, it works!